# Rails 3. Inheritance callback method in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance

I have 2 controllers

OauthController and Admin::OauthController. When Admin::OauthController inherited from OauthController.

In OauthController implemented method "callback", which is public.

Admin::OauthController looks like:

```
class Admin::OauthController < OauthController
end
```

Then if I go to the link "/admin/facebook_oauth/callback" **get error**

```
Unknown action
The action 'callback' could not be found for Admin::OauthController
```

But if I add 'callback' method with call super in Admin::OauthController all works.

```
class Admin::OauthController < OauthController    
  def callback
    super
  end
end
```

This behavior appears after migration to Rails 3. Other methods are inherited OauthController without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Error "raise ActionNotFound" raised if we do not have the desired action in the list of "action_methods"

**AbstractController::Base#internal_methods**

```
# A list of method names that should be considered actions. This
# includes all public instance methods on a controller, less
# any internal methods (see #internal_methods), adding back in
# any methods that are internal, but still exist on the class
# itself. Finally, #hidden_actions are removed.
#
# ==== Returns
# * <tt>array</tt> - A list of all methods that should be considered actions.
def action_methods
  @action_methods ||= begin
    # All public instance methods of this class, including ancestors
    methods = public_instance_methods(true).map { |m| m.to_s }.to_set -
      # Except for public instance methods of Base and its ancestors
      internal_methods.map { |m| m.to_s } +
      # Be sure to include shadowed public instance methods of this class
      public_instance_methods(false).map { |m| m.to_s } -
      # And always exclude explicitly hidden actions
      hidden_actions

    # Clear out AS callback method pollution
    methods.reject { |method| method =~ /_one_time_conditions/ }
  end
end
```

**Do not get into the final list "AbstractController::Base#internal_methods"**

```
 # A list of all internal methods for a controller. This finds the first
  # abstract superclass of a controller, and gets a list of all public
  # instance methods on that abstract class. Public instance methods of
  # a controller would normally be considered action methods, so methods
  # declared on abstract classes are being removed.
  # (ActionController::Metal and ActionController::Base are defined as abstract)
  def internal_methods
    controller = self
    controller = controller.superclass until controller.abstract?
    controller.public_instance_methods(true)
  end
```

**And finally the most interesting:**

```
>> ActionController::Base.instance_methods.include?('callback')
=> true
```